# dependencies { compile "com.github.danielnilsson9:color-picker-view:1.4.0@aar" }

Tags: android, compilation

I'm going to use a color picker, which I downloaded from github, in my project. In it's github page the following code is mentioned:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.github.danielnilsson9:color-picker-view:1.4.0@aar"
}
```

I do not know what is it and who should I use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add that to "build.gradle" file.

example:

```
android {
    ...
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile "com.github.danielnilsson9:color-picker-view:1.4.0@aar"
    ...
}
```